# Macro for deleting repeats in a column by trial

Tags: excel, vba

My data looks like this: (This is an example, actual data will be over 100,000 rows)

http://postimg.org/image/6azzfdc8h/

In Column F , I would like to delete all the repeats within each trial of each subject. For example, for subject #1, I would like to delete all repeats that are within the compatible trial 1, with the target as Square.

So the data should like this

http://postimg.org/image/wu47ynrxb/

Comment: Why not using the 'Delete duplicate' function in Excel ?

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from doing this?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: I can't use the delete duplicate function because it will delete all the repeats in column F. What I want is to delete the repeats in each trial of the column. So column F has three trials, I want excel to delete the duplicates in each trial rather than the deleting repeats in the whole column.

Tim Williams- the part I am stuck at is figuring out how I can delete duplicates in a single column, but condition it to only delete duplicates in each trial.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear also to me, like on above comments, why you are not using the "Delete Duplicate" function in Excel. In fact to pass from your data to your desired result, it is enough that you select all columns and then apply the "Delete Duplicate" function. Excel will consider as duplicated values in all columns and not only the column F value.